# Is there any way to send the attachment file uploaded in the Javascript to Python/Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

This code uploads files, but I was not able to integrate my Javascript and Flask code, that said, the files are being received by the frontend but it's not sending it to the backend.

## Javascript

```
//DOM
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

//APP
let App = {};
App.init = (function () {
    //Init
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        const files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        //files template
        let template = `${Object.keys(files)
            .map(file =>   `<div class="file file--${file}">
                                <div class="name"><span>${files[file].name}</span></div>
                                    <div class="progress active"></div>
                                    <div class="done">
                                        <a href="" target="_blank">
                                        
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`)
            .join("")}`;

        $("#drop").classList.add("hidden");
        $("footer").classList.add("hasFiles");
        $(".importar").classList.add("active");
        $(".submit").classList.add("active");
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(".list-files").innerHTML = template;
        }, 1000);

        Object.keys(files).forEach(file => {
            let load = 2000 + (file * 2000); // fake load
            setTimeout(() => {
                $(`.file--${file}`).querySelector(".progress").classList.remove("active");
                $(`.file--${file}`).querySelector(".done").classList.add("anim");
            }, load);
        });
    }

    // trigger input
    $("#triggerFile").addEventListener("click", evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("input[type=file]").click();
    });

    $("#triggerFile2").addEventListener("click", evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("input[type=file]").click();
    });

    // drop events
    $("#drop").ondragleave = evt => {
        $("#drop").classList.remove("active");
        evt.preventDefault();
    };
    $(`#drop`).ondragover = $("#drop").ondragenter = evt => {
        $("#drop").classList.add("active");
        evt.preventDefault();
    };
    $("#drop").ondrop = evt => {
        $("input[type=file]").files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
        $("footer").classList.add("hasFiles");
        $("#drop").classList.remove("active");
        evt.preventDefault();
    };

    //upload more
    $(".importar").addEventListener("click", () => {
        $(".list-files").innerHTML = "";
        $("footer").classList.remove("hasFiles");
        $(".importar").classList.remove("active");
        $(".submit").classList.remove("active");
        setTimeout(() => {
            $("#drop").classList.remove("hidden");
        }, 500);
    });

    // input change
    $("input[type=file]").addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect);
})();
```

## HTML

```
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
    <header>
        <p>
            <span class="up">up</span>
            <span class="load">load</span>
        </p>
    </header>
    <div class="body" id="drop">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true" id="triggerFile"></i>
        <p id="text-upload" class="pointer-none"><a href="" id="triggerFile2">
            <strong>Browse</strong></a> to begin the upload
        </p>
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" />
     </div>
     <footer>
         <div class="divider">
             <span>
                 <AR>FILES</AR>
             </span>
         </div>
         <div class="list-files">
             <!--   template   -->
         </div>
         <button class="importar">Clear</button>
         <button class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"">Submit</button>
      </footer>
</form>
```

## Flask/Python

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app=Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

path = os.getcwd()
# file Upload
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(path, 'uploads')

if not os.path.isdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
    os.mkdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['xlsx', 'xls'])


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No file selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            flash('File successfully uploaded')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            flash('Allowed file types are txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
            return redirect(request.url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '127.0.0.1',port = 5000, debug = False)
```

I have tried these links:

1. https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Ajax-JavaScript-file-upload-example
2. https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-send-a-file-using-javascript-and-python-5038dc39707b
3. https://docs.faculty.ai/user-guide/apis/flask_apis/flask_file_upload_download.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the function you want to call in your html first: `<form method="post" action="{{url_for('upload_file')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">` and pass a name to the input element that detects your uploaded files: `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file[]" />`

Second thing to do is in your `upload_file()`, to get the uploaded files, you just need to use this sample: `uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")`, afterwards, you would be able to access all your files by using a for loop on them  `for file in uploaded_files:`

Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Hello Hassan, thanks for your answer but as I'm new to doing this, I didn't understand it. I'm sorry!

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest watching some tutorials on how flask and jinja2 work, after that you can come back to my answer.  It's kinda complicated to understand it without knowing the flask's concept. Good luck!